# Report Viewer Preview mscorlib error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, reportviewer, rdlc

I am currently using VS2008 with RDLC version 9. The program is a C# .NET program. When I run the program, everything works fine. I can search up my database, connect to it, and view it in a datagridview.

However, my issue is that, when I click on the tab containing the report viewer, the report starts to load and I get the following:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\IsolatedStorage\os3e4koo.m3d\h2zjgd5a.0zc\
StrongName.mcnytcup ql1kuorvuvoru5rlguuiug21\AssemFiles\ReportPageTempFile-
22e7a412-7b42-43ad-a75b-5f13a001c83e'.
```

From VS2008, if I click Continue, the reports loads fine, and every time I look at the report tab, the error doesn't reappear until I close and reload the dialog. Any ideas what this could be?

Answer (score 1):

Does your SQL Database name have any symbols or punctuation in it? I have seen this cause an issue before

For example Database.V1234

Comment: The database uses an _. The naming scheme is Program_Client.db.

Comment: Have you tried renaming this, I am fairly sure the _ is fine but its the . I have had issues in the past.

Comment: This error does not occur on another machine belonging to my colleague. We both connect to the same database and I just pulled an exact copy of his code. This is something new and strange to us.

Comment: Did you try removing the . from the database name?  Are they the Same OS?

Comment: The . is just for the file name with extension. We're trying something a little more intense after some more initial testing.

Comment: So, turns out that was I was seeing was something due to Common Language Runtime Exceptions being turned on for Thrown. Normally these errors are skipped over, but with that turned on, it was causing all kinds of weird things.

Comment: The comment above should be an answer.